# DOM Attr class usage example

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domdocument

I'm working on a project that extends DOM functionality, and I have been unable to provide any reasonable examples of why the `Attr` class exists, and what it could ever be used for.

Given that HTML attributes are always just strings, such as `<input type="date" name="your-birthday" />`, there already exist `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` methods on the `Element` prototype that work directly with the Attribute's value as a string.

A reference of an `Attr` object can be obtained by using `attr = element.attributes[0]`, then it can be interacted with using methods such as `attr.value = "updated value";` for example.

Please can someone enlighten me with a usage example of when I would ever use the `Attr` class directly, given it doesn't have a constructor and as far as I know can't be passed to any methods within the DOM?

Reference:

- `Attr` class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr
- `getAttribute`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute
- `setAttribute`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute
- `hasAttribute`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing it's useful for, is when the DOM document is an [XML document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument) and you want to know the [namespace URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr/namespaceURI) or [namespace prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr/prefix) of the attribute.

To understand why this might be particularly useful, I'll quote the MDN documentation on `Attr.namespaceURI` (emphasis mine):

> *Per the [Namespaces in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/) specification, an attribute does not inherit its namespace from the element it is attached to.* If an attribute is not explicitly given a namespace, it has no namespace.

To illustrate this, consider this example, in which we parse an XML string with [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to create a `XMLDocument` instance:

<sup>I deliberately gave `<book>` two attributes with ambiguous local names `id`, to illustrate its usefulness.</sup>

```js
const XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
<books xmlns:lib="http://example.com/xml/library">\
  <book id="book-one" lib:id="1">\
  </book>\
</books>';

var parser = new DOMParser;
var doc = parser.parseFromString( XML, 'application/xml' );

// is our Document an instance of XMLDOcument?
console.log( doc instanceof XMLDocument );

// fetch all Attr instances of the first <book> element
var attributes = doc.querySelector( 'book' ).attributes;
for( var attribute of attributes ) {
  // output namespace info about the Attr instance
  console.log( attribute.localName, attribute.prefix, attribute.namespaceURI, attribute.value );
}
```

---

Another use case would be if you wanted to move an `Attr` node to another `Element`:

```
div2.setAttributeNode( div1.removeAttributeNode( div1.getAttributeNode( 'class' ) ) );
```

---

Granted, I don't think the above examples are exemplary of common usage. That's probably why `Element.getAttributeNode()`, `Element.getAttributeNodeNS()`, `Element.setAttributeNode()` and `Element.setAttributeNodeNS()` are [marked as obsolete on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element#Methods).

However, the DOM specs on [w3c.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-core) are not as definitive yet (see the warning in section `8.2 DOM Core`) and neither are the DOM specs on [whatwg](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element)